# SQLite insert statement: SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I can't see what I've messed up, is anyone else seeing an issue?

I can't seem to work out whats the matter, I've added and removed brackets everywhere possible and ran with each new bracket it I added

Current code

```
    package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RegistrationController implements Initializable {

    Connection connection;

    public RegistrationController() {
        connection = SQLConnection.Connector();
        if (connection == null)
            System.exit(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }



    @FXML
    private TextField txtFName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtSName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPasswd;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtAge;

    @FXML
    private Label lblTest;

    public void Submit(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            String query = ("INSERT INTO member(name,surname,age,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            PreparedStatement pst;
            pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, txtFName.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtSName.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtUName.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtPasswd.getText());
            pst.setString(5, txtAge.getText());

            pst.executeUpdate();

            pst.close();

            lblTest.setText("Connected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Back(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml").openStream());
            // ProfileController profileController =
            // (ProfileController)loader.getController();
            // profileController.GetUser(txtUsername.getText());
            primaryStage.close();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Yet again can the downvoter provide feedback so I can fix my issue instead of downvoting and disappearing

Comment: It should be `insert into.. values .. `. SQL is invalid so you are getting error

Comment: Try `...) VALUES (...` instead of `...) (...`?

Comment: my bad guys, added the values, noticed 30 seconds after posting, no error, lable shows as "Connected" like in the code but no update in the db @VeeraKannadiga

Comment: Perhaps you could just post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line should be:-

```
String query = ("INSERT INTO member(name,surname,age,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Note the `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: noticed that 30 seconds after the post, edited it in to the code, no error but the db does not update :/

Comment: I would try hardcoding some values and then run that.  I can't see an obvious reason why nothing would be inserted into the database.  Is it definitely running that bit of code?

Comment: Being such a fool, my db wasnt updating because I misplaced my db file, apologies, your answer helped me notice though, I'll accept when I can :)